# How to make commands that can be disabled in Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wanted to know if anyone knew how to make Discord.py commands that can be disabled with another command. It doesn't matter if we have to use something like Json, I just would like a way.

Answer (score 2):

Use `command.update()` with the kwarg `enabled`

```py
@bot.command()
async def foo(ctx):
    await ctx.send('whatever')


@foo.error
async def foo_error(ctx, error):
    """Simply an error handler"""
    if isinstance(error, commands.DisabledCommand):
        await ctx.send('Command is disabled')


@bot.command()
async def disable_foo(ctx):
    """Disabled the `foo` command"""
    foo.update(enabled=False)


@bot.command()
async def enable_foo(ctx):
    """Enables the `foo` command"""
    foo.update(enabled=True)
```

If the command is disabled, `commands.DisabledCommand` is going to be thrown.
[Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=disable#discord.ext.commands.Command.update)

Comment: And this will reset with each server, right?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Like, if I were to disable a command in one server, it will still be enabled in the others.

Comment: Nope, the command will be disabled in all guilds

Comment: Is there a way to make it server specific?